# Adding arbitrary http headers with defaults in Swagger for R Plumber

Tags: r, swagger, plumber

I have added Bearer token authorization to my Swagger (created with Plumber), using the [solution here](https://github.com/rstudio/swagger/issues/23).

Now I would like to add arbitrary headers that are a part of the request. My plumber deployment is used by a React dashboard, where parsing `req$HTTP_TENANT` gives me the desired value. And it is this I would like to recreate in Swagger.

Consider this example:

```
library(plumber)

r <- plumber::pr("plumber.R") %>%
  plumber::pr_set_docs("swagger") %>%
  plumber::pr_set_api_spec(function(spec) {
    spec$components$securitySchemes$bearerAuth$type <- "http"
    spec$components$securitySchemes$bearerAuth$scheme <- "bearer"
    spec$components$securitySchemes$bearerAuth$bearerFormat <- "JWT"
    spec$security[[1]]$bearerAuth <- ""
    
    spec$components$parameters$HTTP_TENANT <- "HTTP_TENANT"
    spec$parameters[[1]]$HTTP_TENANT <- "Customer name"
    
    spec
  })

r %>% plumber::pr_run(port = 8000, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

This gives the following result:

[image: Working authorization in Plumber's Swagger]

1. How can arbitrary headers be requested, for example `HTTP_TENANT`, maybe typed below the Bearer token input? It could also be somewhere else at the top of Swagger.
2. How can default values be provided for the headers, e.g. `Customer name`, but also the Bearer token (i.e. it could be programmatically entered from R)?

Answer (score 0):

In Swagger, you can add a parameter to the API endpoint and change the "in" property to "header" to request any header, such as HTTP_TENANT. For instance:

```
spec$paths$"/endpoint"$get$parameters[[1]]$name <- "HTTP_TENANT"
spec$paths$"/endpoint"$get$parameters[[1]]$in <- "header"
spec$paths$"/endpoint"$get$parameters[[1]]$description <- "Customer name"
```

Under the "parameters" section of the Swagger UI, an input field for the "HTTP_TENANT" header will be added as a result of this.

A "default" property on the parameter object can be added to headers to provide default values. For instance:

```
spec$paths$"/endpoint"$get$parameters[[1]]$default <- "customer1"
```

The default values could also be set programmatically by reading them from an external source (like a configuration file) or by using an R package that handles authentication (like httr) to handle the bearer token automatically.

Comment: So it turns out that OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.0 do not have a concept of global parameters. There are existing feature requests: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1577